# QLThumbnailGenerator starts failing when called multiple times (on actual device) iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I am trying to create thumbnail images of multiple Wallet Passes (.pkpass) by running a loop over all (around 200) passes in a specific folder and calling generateBestRepresentation(for:) for each of them.

This is the code:

```
let passesDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("Passes")
let size = CGSize(width: 1600, height: 1600)
let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

if let passURLs = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
    at: self.passesDirURL,
    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
    options: .skipsHiddenFiles
    ),
   !passURLs.isEmpty {
    for passURL in passURLs {
        // Create the thumbnail request.
        let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(
            fileAt: passURL,
            size: size,
            scale: scale,
            representationTypes: .thumbnail
        )

        // Retrieve the singleton instance of the thumbnail generator and generate the thumbnails.
        let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
        generator.generateBestRepresentation(for: request) { thumbnail, error in
            if let error = error as? QLThumbnailError {
                print ("Thumbnail generation error: \(error)")
                print ("Thumbnail generation localizedDescription: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print ("Thumbnail generation errorUserInfo: \(error.errorUserInfo)")
                print ("Thumbnail generation errorCode: \(error.errorCode)")
            } else {
                print ("Thumbnail generation OK")
                //do something with thumbnail here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on the simulator, but on an actual device (iPhone Xs Max) sooner or later I start getting errors and the thumbnail generation fails for a big fraction of the passes. The output looks as follows:

```
Thumbnail generation error: related decl 'e' for QLThumbnailError(_nsError: Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=3 "No thumbnail in the cloud for file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DCF703F7-9A1A-4340-86EB-42579D678EEF/Documents/Passes/pass123.pkpass" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DCF703F7-9A1A-4340-86EB-42579D678EEF/Documents/Passes/pass123.pkpass})
Thumbnail generation localizedDescription: The operation couldn’t be completed. (QLThumbnailErrorDomain error 3.)
Thumbnail generation errorUserInfo: ["NSErrorFailingURLKey": file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DCF703F7-9A1A-4340-86EB-42579D678EEF/Documents/Passes/pass123.pkpass]
Thumbnail generation errorCode: 3
```

The error description sounds confusing ("No thumbnail in the cloud for file") as these are not iCloud files.

As the error does not occur when calling the thumbnail generation individually, this seems to be some memory/performance issue. I tried to workaround in many ways, including using a semaphore in the for loop waiting for the completion of one call of generateBestRepresentation to start the next call, which reduced but not eliminated the issue. The only way it worked without error was adding a very long sleep (5 seconds) after the semaphore.wait() statement, but this is no acceptable solution.

Another way I tried was using saveBestRepresentation (as suggested in Apple's documentation), but this did not solve the issue.

Has anyone faced a similar issue and was able to find an acceptable solution?